# express-hHandlebars partials, how can we put subfolders into partial?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

If we have this folder structure.

```
>partials
file3.handlebars

 >subfolder1
   file1.handlebars

 >subfolder2
   file2.handlebars
```

I know that we can call file3 simply by using {{> file3}} into our template, but how can we call file1(that is inside subfolder1) and file2??

Answer (score 2):

It's was obvious, a simple:

```
{{> subfolder1/file1}}
{{> subfolder2/file2}}
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
 {{> subfolder1.file1 }}
 {{> subfolder2.file2 }}
```

Comment: i already tried it, it returns:
" Error: The partial subfolder1.file1 could not be found "